# XCode 5.1.1 "Capture OpenGL ES frame" is disabled

Tags: ios7, opengl-es-2.0, xcode5.1

I have an OpenGL ES 2.0 app. I could capture OpenGL ES frames when I was using XCode 5.0.2. Recently I upgraded my XCode to 5.1.1. I am not able to capture OpenGL ES frames anymore. The camera icon which is used for capturing frames is grey. I runn my app on iOS 7.

Does anybody get the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Greyed out?  Are you running in the simulator?

Other things to check:

- In the docs, it says to ensure that frame capture is enabled in the scheme (In the Run options).
- There's also a Debug->Capture OpenGL ES Frame.  Does that work for you?